# How can I add a reference to a library to my project?

Tags: c#

I bought the Siticon Framework. I have to download the Siticon Manager and the Library, but now I don't know how to import the Library ?

I added the reference, normally it has to give you more options in the toolbox with a special section "Siticon", but it doesn't do it with me…

I also try "using Siticone.UI;"

Can someone help me ?

Sorry for my bad English, I am French

Comment: You may either: have new type of projects pre-configured if it's like Syncfusion, or you may have to add references to these libs in your project. Also, they provide support you can ask for at https://siticoneframework.com/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have got project ABC that needs to reference Siticon library.

1. Right-click on ABC .csproj in Visual Studio
2. Add > Reference
3. See if you can find Siticon library in the list.
4. Alternatively click Browse and look for the .dll

Answer (score 0):

The Siticone Framework Manager is simply there to help you activate, deactivate your license, see remaining days, etc. The library (DLL) with Siticone Tools can be found in a Siticone Library DLL zip file * which can be downloaded on the same website [www.siticoneframework.com](http://www.siticoneframework.com).

You may use FireFox or any browser to get the file. Importing the library should be pretty straightforward. The most easiest way is this:

1. Create a new tab in the Visual Studio IDE Toolbox and name it anything meaningful e.g. Siticone Controls *
2. Drag and drop the Siticone.UI.dll * file onto the newly created tab.
3. Drag and drop any control e.g. Siticone Slider or Siticone Button onto a WinForm or Panel.

Visual Studio will automatically add a reference pointing to Siticone.UI.dll * and copy the file to your BIN folder.

That's all!

Alternatively you can do this:

1. Right-click in the newly created tab e.g. Siticone Controls Tab and left-click "choose items.."
2. Locate the Siticone.UI.dll you have downloaded via the "browse" button
3. Double-click the Siticone.UI.dll file *

Visual Studio will load all the Components in the library so give it a few seconds.

4. When loading is completed, click "Ok"

Visual Studio will automatically add a reference pointing to Siticone.UI.dll * and copy the file to your BIN folder.

---

This process is the same when using most versions of Visual Studio IDE. I tried it on VS 2010, 2015 and 2019.

Hope it helps!

---

- The most latest version is now Siticone Desktop UI v2.0.4 as of 1 May 2021. The library can be downloaded on their website ([www.siticoneframework.com](http://www.siticoneframework.com)) or via the Nuget Package Store here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Siticone.Desktop.UI